# display total likes of every post without page refresh after every 1 second

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, facebook

I am making a facebook like liking system using php and ajax.When the user hits the like i successfully insert and update the likes in table using ajax on database.Now my question is how to check the post likes and if there is more likes then display total likes of every post in every second using ajax so that every body knows total likes of all posts please help to complete my project this the last and only thing i want to ask.I hope you understand my question if not in short i want to fetch total likes of every post in every second like facebook fetch its post likes thanks.

Comment: Is there any one able to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax long polling for it.
This link shows many techniques you can use as per your requirement.
http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: but how to make ajax call and how to make mysql query to return every post likes this is my main problem.yes i know setInterval method to get response in every 1 second.

Comment: it´s polling, not pooling. and it will not help in this case, because you can´t use long polling for accessing the graph api.

Comment: thanks for pointing out.
He is not using graph API as per mention in question.

Comment: ah, i guess he is talking abou his OWN like system? the whole question is pretty unclear...

Comment: well, long polling is a good solution then, my bad. +1 for you.

Comment: i want to make facebook like like system i complete all my work except 1 thing i want to fetch total likes of every post in every second how to make that function in ajax thats my question